# Excel, select an outcome based on

Tags: excel

I have 6 letters in a table column (AG36:41) A-F, I want Excel to give me code depending on which letters are in the top 4 rows regardless of the order of the letters. There are 15 different outcomes which I have written (V44:58) I don't know how excel will read the data and determine the correct answer.
So If A, B, C, D are in the top 4 rows I want the code A B C D.

I Have Tried =IF(AND(AG36="C",AG37="B",AG38="A",AG39="D"),V44) but it doesn't work if the order changes. Plus I want all possible combinations, what function do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the screenshot below. With the help of one helper cell at the fourth row in the `AG36:41` range and a lookup table in the `V44:58` range, you can write a vlookup formula: `=VLOOKUP(C6,$B$18:$C$25,2,0)` *(adjust for desired data ranges)*

My example is partial, for illustration, but can easily be expanded.

[image]

Comment: without the helper: `=VLOOKUP(B3&B4&B5&B6,$B$18:$C$25,2,0)` :P

Comment: nice tweak Great @ScottCraner!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm going to sound very ungrateful but is there away of doing this without writing out a lookup table? I'll be writing variations of each of the 15 possible outcomes? Anyway of decreasing time?

Comment: @robert7lee - perhaps, but I can't think of anything at the moment. I suggested this because you wrote: *There are 15 different outcomes which I have written (V44:58)*. You could write the patterns of the all the other outcomes via a formula, then just change the four components and paste them to the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks  Scott Holtzman and ScottCraner, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this: =IF(AND(COUNTIF(H12:H15,"A"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"B"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"C"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"D")), "ABCD").  Not elegant maybe, but I think it meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you for swift reply, can I combine this with OR somehow for the other 14 possible outcomes instead of displaying 'FALSE', for example if A B E F appear in the top 4 rows it will display A B E F?

Comment: How about this: =IF(AND(COUNTIF(H12:H15,"A"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"B"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"C"),COUNTIF(H12:H15,"D")), "ABCD", CONCATENATE(H12,H13,H14,H15)).  That concatenates the cells, if they do not contain ABCD